# Open an app on battery notification

Tags: ios, iphone, background-process

I'm looking for a way to open (or display a notification from) an iphone app when a low battery level notification occurs. Is it possible to perform it if my app is running in background ? I found that an app can't refresh after some minutes in background, but I wonder how many apps can display notifications by their own without being opened.

Thanks.